# Efficient autoload function

Tags: php, performance, autoload

I currently am building my own PHP framework and am creating a lot of directories to store my classes in.

This is my current autoload function:

```
function __autoload($className)
{
    $locations = array('', 'classes/', 'classes/calendar/', 'classes/exceptions/', 'classes/forms/', 'classes/table/', 'classes/user', 'pages/', 'templates/');
    $fileName = $className . '.php';

    foreach($locations AS $currentLocation)
    {
        if(file_exists($currentLocation . $fileName))
        {
            include_once ($currentLocation . $fileName);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Now in my main class file I do have all of the necessary classes already included so that they won't have to be searched for.

Here are my questions:

1. Is this function efficient enough?  Will there be a lot of load time or is there a way for me to minimize the load time?
2. Is include_once() the way that I should go about including the classes?
3. Is there a way that I could write the function to guess at the most popular folders?  Or would that take up too much time and/or not possible?
4. Would namespaces help me at all? (I am reading and learning about them right now.)

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.  Don't waste your time optimizing it until it's actually a bottleneck for your site.

Comment: You might as well add those subdirectories to the `include_path` just load the $filename. Namespaces are not a good approach, but yes, the directory mapping is pretty much what other frameworks misuse them for.

Comment: @mario what is the include_path for?  I looked it up and am a little confused by it.

Comment: @GWW well if I found out now that using a naming convention is better then maybe I should know that right away instead of going back and redoing all of my code?

Comment: http://de2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path traverses a directory list automatically to find the right include() script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is answered very well here: [autoload and multiple directories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1358897/50079)
2. You should probably go with `require`, for two reasons: a) you don't need to have PHP track if the file has been already included, because if it has it won't need to call `__autoload` in the first place and b) if the file cannot be included you won't be able to continue execution anyway
3. The answer for point 1 covers this
4. Not necessarily; you need some namespace-like mechanism to implement faster loading (to only look where you have to) but you can fake it if necessary without using real namespaces

For reference, the interaction between `__autoload` and namespaces is documented [here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php).