# PHP doing an include statement in a single file but many files will be affected

Tags: php

Does someone know how to make a script that is always included in a php file.

For Example, I have an index.php, I wanted to include script.php by doing `include 'script.php';`
Again, I have a login.php and I wanted to include script.php by doing `include 'script.php';`

I think this is very tiring to do and I think this is not a good idea because it is very repetitive. Is there a way where I can include `script.php` without doing include in each of the file? Like I should do that in a single file then everything would be affected.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated and rewarded. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to literally do what you are asking that I know of is through a config option:

[auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)

If your PHP code is OO, you could look into cleaner solutions such as [autoload](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php). Which I would recommend over the `auto_prepend_file`. A step down from that would be just use 1 file that you do include from all of your other files maybe named `init.php`, but then anything else you need included to all of your files you add the include to `init.php`. Not the cleanest solution, but easy and fast to implement and doesn't involve any config changes.

Comment: This has been helpful to me. http://www.codeforest.net/autoload-your-classes-in-php
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

The [PHP configuration](https://www.php.net/ini.core) directive `auto_prepend_file` does this, but I think it's better to use an [autoload](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) function instead. That way, if a class you use is not defined, its source file is automatically located and included. Of course, you have to do a little extra work to structure your filesystem and write the code to locate those files. There are [lots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358897/autoload-and-multiple-directories) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791899/efficient-php-auto-loading-and-naming-strategies) on SO that cover autoloading strategies.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file).

Comment: This will certainly work, although I would tend to advise against it since it's easy to forget that *every* script will have this file added and it can have unintended consequences.

Comment: @Michael so what? Aren't you going to put there anything but some init variables?

Comment: @Michael, excellent point. As your PHP application ages and enters maintenance mode that "so what?" often turns into something that has been forgotten about as the responsibility for the application has changed hands. That config directive is outside the codebase, so it can easily mislead other developers trying to maintain your codebase.