# Organizing my PHP classes

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to re-organize my function-based PHP into OOP. I'm using a lot of JQuery/JSON to interact with individual scripts and loading the results onto the page or into the database.

Question...do I put every class into one large PHP file, always call that file and just use the specific class I need or do I break up each individual class (like I'm doing now with the functions) and loading in each class as needed?

Thanks,
mike

Comment: Does a 100000 LOC file full of classes sound any more sensible than a 100000 LOC file of procedural code?

Comment: I'm new to OOP programming. Still trying to get my head wrapped around it. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

It's usually preferable to have each class in its own file, because then:

- With the help of good naming conventions, classes are easy to find.
- You can make use of **[Autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)**
- Your files are manageable and don't slip into the <10MB zone.

Comment: Check out [PSR-0](http://phpmaster.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/)

Comment: I don't think autoloading is one of the advantages. It's more a disadvantage that you have to set up an autoloader first. You can faster write a simple `require_once "classes.php";`.

Answer (score 4):

Here there's a ± general consensus amongst PHP developers.

Split your code: one class per PHP file. And name the PHP file like the class' name.

A few reasons:

- You may better find your code without strg + f or like
- Your files are easier to manage: you don't need to scroll a lot to find line 5683 of your code.

Comment: That's not NARQ that's NC. Also, I doubt OP knows what NARQ or NC mean.

Comment: For the OPs benefit, NC = Not Constructive, NARQ = Not A Real Question.

Comment: Oh, the good old days when it used to be S&A...

Comment: @MadaraUchiha You're right, changed.

Comment: @deceze S&A does mean..?

Comment: @bwoebi Oh, you greenhorn... ;-3 *Subjective & Argumentative.*

Comment: @deceze and you nostalgic, old man... Thank you :-P

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I actually was going to just put the entire thing on one file and call it. I'm new to OOP. So, it sort of functions exactly as I have it now, using one function per file and calling them as needed?

Answer (score 1):

According to me, you should always split your classes in individual files.
First of all becuase PHP is providing you a amazing tool that is [php's autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) used with [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.spl-autoload-register.php).

You should have a look to this thread if you want to use autoloading: [autoload and multiple directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358897/autoload-and-multiple-directories).

Also of course, having one file per class allows you to:

- Split your code files accordingly to whatever your organization is.
- Find them quicker
- Avoid importing useless code (If you only use class A in a file where class A and B are defined, definition of class B was useless)